# Rails - How do you insert a variable into a regular expression (Regex) for instance assert_match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do something like

```
assert_match /blah blah blah #{@user}/, @some_text
```

but I'm not having any luck with it working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: as drews said, this is already the way

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That is the correct way to insert a variable into a regex:

```
irb(main):001:0> a='Hi'
=> "Hi"
irb(main):002:0> b=/Not #{a}/
=> /Not Hi/
```

So your problem is likely that the assert is failing because of a bad match.  Check the value of @user and @some_text and try [http://rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) to come up with a matching regexp

Comment: regxPlayerVariable = '(.*?)=.*?document\.getElementById(#{pluginPlayeVariable})' in this i applied all above but these are not working

Comment: Javascript and Ruby have slightly different regex syntaxes and engines.

Answer (score 13):

If there's any possibility of the @user string containing special regexp characters, you should modify this to:

```
/blah blah blah #{Regexp.escape(@user)}/
```

Answer (score 3):

you can take a look at %r{}, for example:

`pattern = 'foo'`
`%r{#{pattern}_bar} =~ 'foo_bar_2000'`

Answer (score 1):

assert_match also takes a string, like

```
assert_match("blah blah", 'a string')
```

so the other way to do what you are doing would be to user string interpolation

```
string_to_match = "blah blah #{@user}"

assert_match(string_to_match, 'a string')
```